# How do I name my system?

Tags: 12.04, networking

I want to name my system that when anyone list all the connected pc in local network then my pc ip and name will be display there.

I am using **sudo arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet
**

this command to list the computer in local network.

The result of this command is

```
10.0.0.1    c0:3f:0e:eb:78:24   NETGEAR
10.0.0.2    e0:69:95:eb:47:92   PEGATRON CORPORATION
10.0.0.3    00:21:5c:81:25:85   Intel Corporate
10.0.0.4    28:cf:e9:10:38:e5   (Unknown)
10.0.0.5    94:71:ac:bf:cb:9d   (Unknown)
10.0.0.6    3c:43:8e:41:ea:37   (Unknown)
```

Where as 10.0.0.5 is my ip address which show as **(Unknown)**

I want to replace that **(Unknow)** to some name so that users in local network can identify my pc.

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit two files to change your computers host name /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname

you can edit them like so

```
sudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

this file should contain your systems current HOSTNAME simply change it to what you like

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

## this file needs to be changed to otherwise errors can happen

change whatever your current HOSTNAME is to your new one and you're good to go

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   HOSTNAME

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

you can also try this which should make the new name take affect

```
sudo hostname NEWHOSTNAME
```

you may also need to do the following

```
sudo service networking restart
```

## not done

Comment: I have changed the both file but in network pc listing it not showing the name.

Comment: I updated the answer maybe it will help?

Comment: I have added more description

can you please have look 

i have changed the both files and restarted the pc.

Comment: maybe you're looking for this command avahi-discover

Comment: or perhaps smbtree

Answer (score 0):

The column where (Unknown) shows up for your computer, lists the **vendor** of the network card. The vendor is derived from the unique MAC address of the card: the first 6 hexadecimal digits determine the vendor. To translate these digits to the vendor name, `arp-scan` uses a table stored in `/usr/share/arp-scan/ieee-oui.txt`. So to hack your arp-scan output you will need to reverse engineer the ieee-oui.txt table and add your own line with the MAC address and whatever text you want to show up.
What you probably want though, is a list containing IP addresses and hostnames. The `arp-scan` command will not give you that.

Comment: so can you please suggest the correct way find it out....

or tell me that if I know the hostname then how could I know the IP address of the local machine.

Comment: Technically, to translate hostnames into IP addresses, you would need to store all these in /etc/hosts, or set up a DNS system. You can use `avahi-browse -a` for Linux computers.